# HTTP POST Transmission suggestion

Tags: mysql, xml, post, arduino, real-time

I'm building a system which requires an Arduino board to send data to the server.

The requirements/constraints of the app are:

1. The server must receive data and store them in a MySQL database.
2. A web application is used to graph and plot historical data.
3. Data consumption is critical
4. Web application must also be able to plot data in real time.

So far, the system is working fine, however, optimization is required.

The current adopted steps are:

1. Accumulate data in Arduino board for 10 seconds.
2. Send the data to the server using POST with data containing an XML string representing the 10 records.
3. The server parse the received XML and store the values in the database.

This approach is good for historical data, but not for realtime monitoring. 
My question is: Is there a difference between:

1. Accumulating the data and send them as XML, and,
2. Send the data each second.

In term of data consumption, is sending a POST request each second too much?

Thanks

EDIT: Can anybody provide a mathematical formula benchmarking the two approaches in term of data consumption?

Comment: What are you using to send an HTTP request? GPRS, Wifi ? Both take more than 1 second to send a POST.

Comment: For testing, im using ethernet connection. But later, it will be changed to 3G

Answer (score 0):

For your data consumption question you need to figure out how much each `POST` costs you giving your cell phone plan. I don't know if there is a mathematical formula, but you could easily test and work it out.

However, using 3G (even Wifi for that matter), the *power consumption* will be an issue, especially if your circuit runs on a battery; each POST bursts around 1.5 amps, that's too much for sending data every second.

But again, why would you send data every second?
Real time doesn't mean sending data every second, it means being at least as fast as the system.

For example, if you are sending temperatures, temperature doesn't change from 0° to 100° in one second. So all those `POSTs` will be a waste of power and data.

You need to know how fast the parameters change in your system and adapt your `POST` accordingly.

Comment: Power consumption is not an issue since the system in not battery powered. As for the updates, the system actually updates each second: The system tracks a vehicle. It needs to know every second the new coordinates of the car.

Comment: Ok. But still a `POST` from a GPRS/3G module takes more than 1 second to finish. Try to test if you have one available.